# Invalid left assignment in document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I get an error message (SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment) with this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.grid-template-rows = "1fr 300px repeat(2, 1fr)";
```

Can you not type grid-template-rows as something to change like this? Is there any other way to change grid-template-rows with JavaScript?

Comment: `style.grid-template-rows` is invalid, you can't use `-`, JS is trying to do some math this way... it is probably `...style.gridTemplateRows = ...`

Comment: Most things in JS that are seemingly hyphenated are usually parsed to camelcase.

Answer (score 2):

Change the property name.

The names of CSS properties in JS are slightly different. Use camelCase instead of hyphens:

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.gridTemplateRows = "50px";
```